# Java RMI permission denied to LAN address, works for 127.0.0.1

Tags: java, rmi

I am implementing a Client application and a Server application on my Windows computer using two terminals that communicate with each other.

However I cannot get the Client to run. The Server and Java RMI registry run successfully. I have 3 files: Client.java, Server.java and Hello.java

```
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry; //Client.java
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class Client { 

    private Client() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String host = (args.length < 1) ? null : args[0];
        try {
        
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1", 1099);
            Hello stub = (Hello) registry.lookup("Hello");
            String response = stub.sayHello();
            System.out.println("response: " + response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Client exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.rmi.registry.Registry; //Server.java
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
        
public class Server implements Hello {
        
    public Server() {}

    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }
        
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        try {
            Server obj = new Server();
            Hello stub = (Hello) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 0);

            // Bind the remote object's stub in the registry
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1", 1099);
            registry.bind("Hello", stub);

            System.err.println("Server ready");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.rmi.Remote; //Hello.java
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface Hello extends Remote {
    String sayHello() throws RemoteException;
}
```

All three Java files are located in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\bin. After compiling them to the same directory, I run the following commands in the command prompt as administrator.

1. start rmiregistry -J-Djava.class.path=./

*Java RMI registry starts successfully in a new command prompt window (no output).*

2. start java Server

*Server starts sucessfully in a new command prompt which outputs "Server ready".*

3. java Client

**This command is unsuccessful and outputs the following error:**

```
        java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 192.168.1.13; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:635)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:131)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:235)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:180)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.sayHello(Unknown Source)
        at Client.main(Client.java:15)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:75)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:476)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:162)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:394)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:555)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:451)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:228)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:617)
        ... 7 more

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\bin>_
```

I am unsure how to get the Client running successfully. I disabled windows firewall and am not using a VPN.

Comment: Assuming you are running the Java client command  as administrator, and passing in the IP address. It seems that whatever is causing problems is line 15 of your client code. Does the code throw exceptions if you don't try the hello command?

Comment: If I remove the hello command Hello stub = (Hello) registry.lookup("Hello"); the file does not compile and gives the following error: 
Client.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
            String response = stub.sayHello();
                              ^
  symbol:   variable stub
  location: class Client
1 error

Comment: Also I am running the Java client command as an administrator, but I am not passing in the IP address. I just entered "java Client"

Comment: Is 192.168.1.13 the IP that your server is running on? It seems your client is unable to connect to the server.

Comment: Your code worked for me when I changed the `Server` code. Instead of calling `getRegistry()`, I called `createRegistry()`. I ran both client and server on my local Windows 10 machine.

Comment: For the `Server` code I tried calling `createRegistry()` instead of `getRegistry()` by changing `Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1", 1099);` to `Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry("127.0.0.1", 1099);` and received the following error when trying to compile the `Server` code: 
`Server.java:21: error: no suitable method found for createRegistry(String,int)`

Comment: @jcjunction 192.168.1.13 is the IPv4 address of my computer I am using it because I am trying to host and connect to the server on one machine. I found it in the using ipconfig command.

Comment: 192 addresses are private ip. Not reachable from outside your local network. But if you are running on the same machine that should be fine. The code you posted shows 127.0.0.1 which is localhost. Meanwhile you are starting the server on 192 port. Make sure the 2 IP address line up. Post the exact commands you are running.

Comment: I changed the ip address in the `Server` and `Client` files to `192.168.1.13` which is my private ip. After compiling the 3 files I ran the following commands:
First I type `start rmiregistry -J-Djava.class.path=./` and the Java RMI registry opens sucessfully
Second I type `start java Server` and the server fails to start and shows this error:
`Server exception: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 192.168.1.13; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect`

Comment: Third I type `java Client` and the client also does not connect and shows this error:
`Client exception: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 192.168.1.13; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect`

Comment: Before when I used `127.0.0.1` in the `Server` and `Client` files like in the original post, I was able to start the server but not the client.  After using `192.168.1.13` instead in the two files, the above happens where I cannot start the server or the client.

Comment: So 192.168.1.13 is not your local IP address, in which case there is something wrong with your DNS or `/etc/hosts` file. or you have firewall rules in place preventing you from accessing it.

Comment: Thank you @user207421. I will try to resolve this from what you told me.